# How do I get to my Stack Exchange Inbox? Nothing to click in header area

Tags: support, inbox, notifications

I created this account when I asked a question. Now the header at the top says "Stack Exchange" and there is a red rectangle with the number 9; hovering over it says I have 9 unread messages in my Inbox.

So how the hell do I get to the inbox?

Comment: I suppose it depends on which OS you are using and which browser. I'd start with specifying the details and then perhaps open a private browsing window / try a second browser to see if it's local data cache or related to your account and the server side.

Comment: It works like the Apple menubar: Just click on it and it will unfold...

Answer (score 4):

[image: Click the button]

Comment: With animation and correct number (9) wow...

Answer (score 2):

Click on the number "9" in the bar at the top.  It will expand to show you a list of the messages in your inbox.